# .gitignore to ignore all files, then recursively allows files of a certain type

Tags: git, recursion, directory

I have a folder that is purely a T4 template folder but it outputs code generated files into other directories.  So I'm looking to ignore everything except *.tt files (i.e. the *.cs, *.master, *.resx, etc.).  There is one gotcha.  I have a subfolder called static that contains files that should never be ignored.

```
/Test.tt
/Test.cs
/TestHtml.tt
/TestHtml.html
/Static
   /Sub/Sub.cs
   /Sub/Sub2/Sub2.cs
   /Sub3/Sub4/Sub5/Sub5.html
```

I *only* want to ignore the /Test.cs and /Test.html but include all other files.  I've tried the following:

/.gitignore

```
# Ignore all
*

# But not these files...
!.gitignore
!*.tt
```

/Static/.gitignore

```
!*.*
#also have just tried blank
```

I can't get git to ignore the right things...main problem is the 'recursive exclude' I want for Static/*.*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to anchor your `*` otherwise it will continue to match all files even in un-ignored directories.

e.g.

```
/*

!.gitignore
!*.tt
!/Static/
```

Comment: I've put this in, however, git status shows *.tt (good) and Static/ .  I wasn't sure if Static/ meant it would add all files so I did a git add ., followed by git ls-files, but no files in Static/ were added (note, there are no files present in Static/ until at least one level deep - that is Static/*/*.* is first 'valid' level, but there are deeper levels too).  Any other ideas?

Comment: @Terry: I've just run a test case with this `.gitignore` and it works for me. Do you have any other `.gitignore` files other than the one that I describe or anything in your `.git/info/exclude` or any other custom ignore file?

Comment: I don't have any other `.gitignore` files.  I don't have a `.git/info/exclude` file either.  I do have a global `.gitignore` but it just ignores standard 'Visual Studio Build Files'...(i.e. no mention of *.cs or /Static).  Should I get screen shots and ls dumps into dropbox for examination?

Comment: @Terry: What do `git ls-files -o` and `git ls-files -oi --exclude-standard` show?

Comment: @charles-bailey - -o returns what looks like 'everything' (note, I have not committed/or added to index yet).  -oi --exclude-standard seems to only show the files I want to ignore in the root (correct).  Is this what you expected?  'Seems' right, except for fact that when I do an add . that the ls-files doesn't list andy Static/*/*.* files.

Comment: @Terry: In that case I don't understand why add didn't work. What version of git are you using?

Comment: @charles-bailey - recent ;)  How do I check?  New to git.

Comment: @charles-bailey - 1.7.4.msysgit.0

Comment: @Terry: What happens if you try `!/[Ss]tatic/` instead?

Comment: I have a practically identical requirement but this doesn't work. Ignoring the 'Static' folder requirement... Create a new repo (git init), add a .gitignore file as above, create a new folder 'test1', create 2 files in that folder include.tt & dontinclude.foo, do a 'git add .' and a 'git status' & *all files* are ignored... I tried it with git 1.7.3 & then with 1.7.7 - am I missing something?

Comment: @PandaWood: Did you unignore the `test1` directory as `Static` is in the example?

Comment: I had to add !*/ to not ignore all subdirectories - otherwise basically nothing is found unless it's in the root directory - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024924/gitignore-ignore-all-files-then-recursively-allow-foo

Comment: @PandaWood: That sounds correct, it's what should happen if you are ignoring everything at the top level (i.e. `/*`). An ignored directory shouldn't be searched by git for new files.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
/*
!.gitignore
!*.tt
!/Static/
```

should work.

Look at my answer below for making it more complex when you want to `unignore`  a subdirectory within some other folder when you are ignoring everything else.

[Can't understand how gitignore ignores the folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738204/cant-understand-how-gitignore-ingnores-the-folders/5740857#5740857)