# Ignore files then recursively allow .keep within a single directory

Tags: git, gitignore

This question is very similar to the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8025106/882428

The difference being that I'm trying to do it for a single directory rather than the entire project.

I have the following directory structure:

```
/temp/
/temp/local/
/temp/remote/
```

Each directory has files within it that I would not like tracked, but I also include a `.keep` file to ensure the folders exist, but there can also be any number of other folders within `/temp/`.

I've tried dozens of configurations but either get nothing new in my `git status` or all of the files.

Answer (score 0):

How about this `.gitignore`:

```
/temp/local/*
!/temp/local/.keep
/temp/remote/*
!/temp/remote/.keep
```

It should ignore everything but the `.keep` file in those directories.

You could also simply use this `.gitignore`:

```
/temp/local/
/temp/remote/
```

In this case you have to add the files explicitly using something like `git add temp/{local,remote}/.keep`.

But most of the time the even better approach is changing you application to create all the directories it needs.