# .gitignore for Jenkin's config files

Tags: git, jenkins, gitignore

I'm using this `.gitignore` in the Jenkins directory:

```
*
!.gitignore
!jobs/*/config.xml
jobs/**/modules**/config.xml
```

But everything is ignored by Git. What am I doing wrong?

New Version regarding this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162919/whitelisting-and-subdirectories-in-git/9227991#9227991)- works almost fine:

```
#Ignore everything
*
#Don't ignore directories
!*/
#Don't ignore these files
!/.gitignore
!jobs/*/config.xml
!jobs/**/modules**/config.xml
```

But .gitignore files in subfolders aren't ignored. I want to except only the root .gitignore.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whitelisting and subdirectories in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162919/whitelisting-and-subdirectories-in-git)

Comment: Check out these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9227991/1228454 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/8025106/1228454

Comment: I think that * should be removed

Comment: I read several .gitignore posts on stackoverflow but... the inapplicable ones.

Apologize my double post.

Answer (score 2):

Last year, I contributed a .gitignore to GitHub gitignore project.  It covers tracking all of your Jenkins configs using git.

https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/1763