# Ignore everything in a specific directory but exclude some files in the ignored directory

Tags: git, gitignore

In my git repo, I have several directories. I'm ignoring One among many directories completely. But I want to exclude (whitelist) a single file which is nested in that directory. Something like this

```
!*/Databases/
!Databases/Links_Databases.txt
!Databases/AFLW/README.txt
```

Here the second line works, but the third line doesn't work. Nested README.txt file is still ignored. How can I whitelist that file?

I found few answers here: [One](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8025106/3337089), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9227991/3337089) and [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/987162/3337089). But the solutions provided here ignores everything in the root directory. I'll have to manually whitelist other directories I want to include. So, it didn't serve my purpose.

Preferably, I would like to edit my main gitignore file only. If there is no other way, I'm okay with creating another gitignore in a subdirectory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to *'unignore'* the directory under which the file resides:

```
# Ignore all contents of Databases directory
Databases/*
# Except this direct child file
!Databases/Links_Databases.txt
# And the relevant subdir
!Databases/AFLW/
# Ignore all contents in subdir
Databases/AFLW/*
# Except this file we want to keep
!Databases/AFLW/README.txt
```

Although it's not strictly a duplicate, there is a very similar question with good explanations in the answers here: [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

Comment: That worked! Thanks. So, If my file is nested deep in the structure, I'll have to repeat this. Right? Unignore a directory, ignore everything under it, unignore, ignore... till I reach my required file. Is there any possible shortcut?

Comment: Read the link where the explanations are very clear on the subject. TLDR; => no there is no shortcut.