Add unexcluded files and folders
There is a project with .gitignore in root folder:
*
!.gitignore

I need to add new folder to the project:
/new_folder/file_1
/new_folder/file_2
/new_folder/subfolder/file_3

So I added to .gitignore a line at the end:
*
!.gitignore
!new_folder

But Git is not seeing this new_folder as if it does not exist.

git track files not folder (your file_1 is a good start), add the file and use --force. something like git add --force new_folder\*

@Bagus Tesa, thank you!

This is crazy. I tried all sorts of ways to use the ! syntax to un-ignore files under new_folder, and it looks like there is no way to do it after a *. I tried !new_folder/file_1, !./new_folder/file_1, !new_folder, !./new_folder, !./new_folder/* and even force adding another file in that folder, but in all cases git check-ignore -v new_folder/file_1 confirms that the * lines causes the file to be ignored and my ! patterns afterwards had no effect.

While git add --force is a good work-around for OP, does someone know how to write a .gitignore file that would have worked?

@joanis have you tried to use !new_folder/*? using * to ignore some stuffs is kind of an overkill imho.

@BagusTesa Yeah, I tried it, it didn't help.

Found it. If I add !*/ at the end, after !file1 or !new_folder/file1, it now works. https://stackoverflow.com/a/987162/3216427

Other duplicate candidates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9162919/3216427 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/8024924/3216427 (both links found in comments to https://stackoverflow.com/q/987142/3216427 ).

Get into the habit of adding a trailing / for directory names. You'll save yourself some trouble later.
