# gitignore directory exception not working

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following folder structure:

```
public
    media
        catalog
            product
            category
        private
        tmp
        var
        test
```

I want to gitignore everything in the `media` directory except for `catalog/category` and `private`

My gitignore I am trying is:

```
public/media/*
!public/media/catalog/category/
!public/media/private
```

But it doesn't work.  Any new files added to the `category` or `private` directories are not available to add.

I could just git add force but I would like this done through the gitignore if possible

Comment: See the following question which is very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001126/git-ignore-all-except-subfolder

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's usually simplest to put just a `.gitignore` at the level where it starts to matter. (This also helps if you ever split a repository or move directories around.) In this case you need to ignore everything except `catalog` and `private` in the `public/media` folder so in `public/media/.gitignore` put:

```
/*
!/catalog/
!/private/
```

and in `public/media/catalog/.gitignore` put:

```
/*
!/category/
```

It's important (and the reason that your rules are not working) not to ignore the `public/media/catalog` directory itself, as otherwise everything in it will be ignored, even if you didn't want to ignore a specific part of its contents.

Of course, you can combine this into a single ignore at the `public/media` level if you like:

```
/*
!/catalog/
!/private/
/catalog/*
!/catalog/category/
```

Comment: Ok this works.  Its a little bit of a pain actually, since i had 1 nice gitignore but now have 3.  But it works thank you

Comment: @MartyWallace: You can have a single `.gitignore` if you prefer (I only counted 2 in my answer), I just find the patterns get more complex.

Answer (score 9):

**Solution with a single `.gitignore` file in the repo root directory**

You tried to use one `.gitignore` file at the repository's root level. Like you, I usually also centralize all ignores like this to keep things tidy. In this case it is difficult though, because "It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded" [[source](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)].

My ugly solution for this restriction, which I also explore in my related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25475163) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25477677): re-include all parent directories along the path before re-including your desired file, while keeping other files in these parent directories out by re-excluding them.

With that, your `.gitignore` patterns would be:

```
public/media/**
!public/media/private
!public/media/catalog/

public/media/catalog/**
!public/media/catalog/category/
```

Comment: Yes! The /** is very important

Comment: /** made all the difference. Thanks!