# .gitignore - Ignore everything in a directory except one file

Tags: gitignore

I know there is a lot of questions like this, but no one solved my problem. I want something very simple - ignore all files and folders under specific folder except one file. This is what I try:

```
#Ignore
public/typings/*

#Allow
!public/typings/browser/ambient/jquery/jquery.d.ts
```

...but the file is still ignored.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the file was added in a previous commit before you put it in git ignore, it's possible your .gitignore is not working. I had the same problem few days ago. I solved the problem thanks to this post:

[Post int randallkent](http://www.randallkent.com/2010/04/30/gitignore-not-working/)

I hope this helps you

EDIT:

solution was found here:  [gitignore directory exception not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678936/gitignore-directory-exception-not-working)

Comment: and did you read this too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678936/gitignore-directory-exception-not-working 
If this doesn't works, I'm afraid I have not more solutions. Sorry man

Comment: Ooooh.... thank you so much! This helped. Single file solution looks a little bit strange but at least works :)

Comment: @DanieloFair so the first part of your answer is not necessary? just to do what's indicated in your second link?

Answer (score 47):

It seems `!` only works if the file is in the same folder. A possible workaround would be to nest the same statement till you get to your final file. A bit messy, but it works.

```
public/typings/*
!public/typings/browser
public/typings/browser/*
!public/typings/browser/ambient
public/typings/browser/ambient/*
!public/typings/browser/ambient/jquery
public/typings/browser/ambient/jquery/*
!public/typings/browser/ambient/jquery/jquery.d.ts
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, man. Actually @DanieloFair pointed me the discussion with the answer, but yeah, my `.gitignore` now looks like your example.

Comment: To be honest, I think this should be the accepted answer, since it gives a direct solution.

Answer (score 3):

I've been struggling a lot with this subject, let me share a procedure that worked for me:

1) Add the top level folder "abc/" to your .gitignore
2) Let's say that in "abc/" you have also "def/" and "jkl/" folders. If you want to keep the contents of "jkl/" you can just do:

```
git add -f jkl/*.php
```

Ok! Now everything inside "jkl/" with .php extension will be tracked by git, even in the next commits, without any headaches!

I've found this to be the right solution for my case, because I was really going insane trying to understand how gitignore does scan files and directories.