# How can I .gitignore all files in directory except those starting with pattern?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following directory structure:

```
project
  modules
    some-company-foo
    different-company-bar
    mycompany-a
    mycompany-b
    mycompany-c
```

How can I ignore all the files in modules, except those that **start with** `mycompany`?

Similar to [git ignore all except subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001126/git-ignore-all-except-subfolder), but using a wildcard. I don't want to have to maintain a list of every `mycompany-...` folder in `.gitignore`.

Based on other answers, I've tried creating `modules/.gitignore` with the following contents:

```
/*
# Do not ignore mycompany modules
!/mycompany*
```

And `modules` isn't mentioned in `project/.gitignore` at all.

But this doesn't work. Eg,

```
git add /Users/mike/Documents/project/modules/mycompany-faq/questions/somefile.md
```

Fails with:

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
modules/mycompany-faq/questions/somefile.md
Use -f if you really want to add them
```

**How can I ignore all the files in `modules`, except those that start with `mycompany`**?

Comment: Which version of Git are you using? It works for me.

Comment: `git version 2.7.4 (Apple Git-66)`

Comment: @JonathanWakely I've figured out the answer thanks to your test - do you want to paste 'this works as is' so you get the points? I'll add what was causing the problem.

Comment: I've got enough rep, glad you figured it out. N.B. that paste.fedoraproject.org link will expire at some point, copy the content into your answer if you want to preserve the info,.

Comment: @JonathanWakely But you're on 94K - you could get a mug and some stickers! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291791/what-do-i-get-with-100k-reputation 

Answer (score 1):

*@jonathanwakely Add your own answer and I'll give you the points instead!*

The config was actually correct - thanks to [@jonathanwakely's demo](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/387815/14676348/), which worked in a new folder.

The problem was that a higher level `.gitignore` file  - above the top of the project, was ignoring the `modules` directory.

I'd looked for `~/Documents/.gitignore` and `~/.gitignore` previously, but **there's another `.gitignore` with a different name**. I was able to find it with:

```
> git check-ignore -v modules/mycompany-faq/questions/ssl-or-https.md

/Users/mike/.gitignore_global:28:modules    modules/mycompany-foo/somefile.md
```

I.e., `.gitignore_global` was set to ignore the `modules` directory.

Answer (score -1):

[On the .gitignore manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

> It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that
>   file is excluded.

So you need to specify fullpath, like

```
!/Users/mike/Documents/project/modules/mycompany*
```

Comment: But the OP says _"And modules isn't mentioned in project/.gitignore at all.

"_

Comment: He ignores /*. So git doesn't scan it see what's inside, and doesn't designore files inside.

Comment: That's in the `modules` sub-directory, and the manual you linked to says: _"An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; **any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again.**"_

Comment: The parent is ignored before, so git will not see what's inside, and cannot file the modules/ directory. Please read my answer again.

Comment: I've read it. It's wrong. I've just tested what the OP claims to be doing, and it works. The `modules` directory is **not** excluded, read the question again.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanWakely - indeed, using full paths doesn't change anything.