# Git: inverse ignoring (.gitignore)

Tags: git

I created a repository for my home folder. This is my `.gitignore` file:

```
!.vim/plugin/*
!.vim/doc/*
.*
*
.viminfo
.vim/.netrwhist
.vim-fuf-data/file/stats
bin/dwm/dwm
```

So when I create a new file inside `.vim/plugin` I expected that after `git status` this file was shown, but no..why?

**EDIT**: after a pair of answers I changed the position of inverse ignoring lines this way below, but the problems is the same: the new files I create inside the `.vim/plugin` folder are not shown after `git status`..

```
.*
*
.viminfo
.vim/.netrwhist
.vim-fuf-data/file/stats
bin/dwm/dwm
!.vim/plugin/*
!.vim/doc/*
```

Comment: Is `git st` an alias for `git status`?

Comment: Yes, when set in the .gitconfig file

Comment: I tried those shorthand commands, bad habit from svn...

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior at my site. I suspect that it is not possible to "unignore" subfolders of ignored folders.

Comment: @Nobody Yes, that's possible. The problem is the `*`, but I haven't figured out why, yet.

Comment: @Deve: Maybe it should be `/*` instead, it could be that `*` matches `.` and therefore ignores the containing directory itself.

Comment: @Nobody Unfortunately, no. I tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to tell git to only include certain files instead of ignoring certain files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279533/is-there-a-way-to-tell-git-to-only-include-certain-files-instead-of-ignoring-cer)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In line 4 you're ignoring everything with `*`. This overrides the previous negating pattern. From the [man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html):

> within one level of precedence, the last matching pattern decides the
>   outcome

Where "level of precedence" means different sources for ignore patterns like `.gitignore` and `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude`.

If you want to ignore everything but the patterns beginning with `!` you should move the `*` to the beginning of `.gitignore`

---

**Edit**

I found a solution with the help of [another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162919/git-whitelisting-files-in-a-complex-directory-structure):

```
*
!*/
!.vim/plugin/*
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to ignore only top level files and directories, and in the whitelisted directories do the same if necessary, as in [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738204/cant-understand-how-gitignore-ignores-the-folders/5740857#5740857)

For example my .gitignore now looks like this

```
/*
!.gitignore
!.vimrc
!.bashrc
!.vim/
.vim/.netrwhist
!.gconf/
.gconf/apps/*
!.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal
!bin/
```

The answer of Deve makes git very slow because it searches all directories under your homedir. (In the specific case of using git for the settings in your homedir)

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the negated lines (those starting with `!`) to the bottom of the `.gitignore` file.

See the [Examples section here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html)