# wanting to ignore ../../../packages but not ../packages/... if you know what I mean

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a directory structure where I want to include a /packages/ directory in just one section and ignore in the others.  The problem is with nuget and Microsoft, I don't want to backup my packages, but another library requires it.

what might my .gitignore look like assuming I'm already ignoring all packages as follows:

```
# NuGet Packages Directory
####packages
```

but I dont want to ignore

```
/WebAPI/JavaScript/Packages
```

Comment: By “`..`”, do you mean something other than parent directory?!

Comment: can you give a concrete example of your folder structure. I think your question title is contradicting your content. Or maybe you have .gitignore stored somewhere else than in your repo root? Don't recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Git: inverse ignoring (.gitignore)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398648/git-inverse-ignoring-gitignore) I think you can do this:

```
packages/
!../packages/
```

The second line "undoes" part of the first.