# Is it possible to use git within another application?

Tags: git, github, repository, localhost

I have an application with it's own files on my C:\wamp\www\project localhost. I want to use git to only keep track of the custom files I add to the project. This project has existing files of course because it is a web application. I would like to be able to switch between versions of my project and replace files automatically within my localhost. Is it possible to do this? I am new to git and as I research this topic, it just confuses me more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Git can be a good choice for versioning the configuration of an app.  If your requirements are not met by using Git, you'll have to consider a [configuration management tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software), such as [CFEngine](http://cfengine.com/), [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/), [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home), [Chef](https://www.getchef.com/chef/) or [Salt](http://www.saltstack.com/community/).

These links will help you get started using Git to version your configuration:

- [Use git for multiple server configuration files](https://serverfault.com/questions/249792/use-git-for-multiple-server-configuration-files)
- [How To Use Git to Manage your User Configuration Files on a Linux VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-to-manage-your-user-configuration-files-on-a-linux-vps)
- [Managing Configuration Changes with Git](http://www.opennms.org/wiki/Managing_Configuration_Changes_with_Git)

The key parts for this task if you are new to Git will be the [`.gitignore`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398648/git-inverse-ignoring-gitignore) file to set which configuration files you want to track, and [`git checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) to switch between configuration versions.