# how to use .gitignore reverse select

Tags: git, gitignore

use .gitignore to reverse selection,I just want to track the app catalog.App is the secondary directory under emply.

[image]

l used The following code,But git doesn't track anything

```
*
!*/
!*/app
```

I have already tested similar problems, Write like it, but invalid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: inverse ignoring (.gitignore)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398648/git-inverse-ignoring-gitignore)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignore everything, unignore top-level app and everything under it:

```
*
!/app/
!/app/*
```

Comment: it doesn't work,Have you tested it,only !filename work

Comment: I used the wrong directory name just now.you are true,thank you

Answer (score 7):

I just had a slightly more tricky problem and ended up here, so if this is the case for you as well, here goes:

If you **ignore a concrete directory** (e.g. /Emply/ in this case) but want to include some of its **sub-directories or included files**, this will **not work**:

```sh
/Emply/
!/Emply/app  # Does not work!
```

The reason is that git will not list ignored directories for performance reasons ([source](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format)). Instead, use the wildcard to ignore all sibling directories and files:

```sh
/Emply/*
!/Emply/app  # Works!
```

It's a bit obscure and just drove me mad.

Answer (score 1):

Albeit [@phd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54702576/11127541)'s answer is correct. It won't work if you have other directories nested inside. This should be a more foolproof solution.

```bash
*
!/app/
!/app/**/*
```